# Limit of sequence: $\frac{27^{\frac{1}{n}}-8^{\frac{1}{n}}}{3^{\frac{1}{n}}-2^{\frac{1}{n}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to calculate the following limit:

$$lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{27^{\frac{1}{n}}-8^{\frac{1}{n}}}{3^{\frac{1}{n}}-2^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

I tried by taking $27^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $3^{\frac{1}{n}}$ in front of the brackets in the numerator and denominator, but I get [1*0/0]... Could you please tell me how to proceed?

Edit:

$$lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]27-\sqrt[n]8}{\sqrt[n]3-\sqrt[n]2}=\\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]3^3-\sqrt[n]2^3}{\sqrt[n]3-\sqrt[n]2}\\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{(\sqrt[n]3-\sqrt[n]2)(\sqrt[n]3^2+\sqrt[n]6+\sqrt[n]2^2)}{\sqrt[n]3-\sqrt[n]2}\\
lim_{n \to +\infty}(\sqrt[n]3^2+\sqrt[n]6+\sqrt[n]2^2)=\\
lim_{n \to +\infty}(\sqrt[n]9+\sqrt[n]6+\sqrt[n]4)=\\
lim_{n \to +\infty}\sqrt[n]9(1+\sqrt[n]\frac{6}{9}+\sqrt[n]\frac{4}{9})=\\1*(1+1+1)=3$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If we denote $u_n := 3^{1/n}$ and $v_n := 2^{1/n}$, then the limit is
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{u_n^3 - v_n^3}{u_n - v_n} .$$ How can we simplify the expression in this latter limit?

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question according to your hint, could you check if this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, though notice that after cancellation we see that we may as well compute $\lim_{x \searrow 0} (9^x + 6^x + 4^x)$, and the function in the limit is continuous at $0$, hence...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  let $a = 3^{1/n}$ and $b = 2^{1/n}$.  Then what are $27^{1/n}$ and $8^{1/n}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?  How would you simplify the resulting expression?

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question, could you check if this is what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

In this very special case, you can carry out the division exactly, as the other answers suggest.  More generally, you would use the fact that
$$
a^x = \exp(x \log a) \sim 1 + x\log a + O(x^2)
$$
as $x\rightarrow 0$.